# Create table in Latex with multi-row and multi-column

Tags: latex, multiple-columns, tabular, overleaf, multirow

I'm attempting to make a table in Latex, but I'm having trouble. I tried a variety of options, but none of them worked for me. I'd want to make a table similar to the one below:
[Here open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZcUd.png)

Can anyone show how to do this in Latex please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the package `multirow` when you need to create such tables in Latex.You can create the table which you needed in latex like below :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\title{Tables}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{A} & B & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{F}      &   &            &           &            &           &            &           \\ \cline{2-8} 
                        &   &            &           &            &           &            &           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This results in a table like below which you wanted :
[image]